# How long do white magic spells last in Final Fantasy I for NES

Tags: final-fantasy

I was wondering how long the white magic spells that affect evasion, attack or defence (such as INVS, FOG, RUSE, etc) last in the first Final Fantasy? Do they last for an entire battle? Of just a limited amount of turns?

Comment: you're right, I'm updating the question.

Comment: Now that you've updated your question, my memory says that depending on the spell, they last for x amount of turns, beyond that I can't say for sure. (hence my answer in a comment, rather than posted.)

Comment: Are you actually playing the NES version or one of the remakes? I know they made some things simpler in the remakes so it may differ.

Comment: I'm playing the Wii version from the WiiWare store.

Comment: I thought they lasted till the end of the battle?

Comment: In my current experience danRhul is right..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases status effects will last until either the end of battle or when the character dies.

Elemental protections (AFIR, AICE, etc.) can also be removed from allies with the XFER spell. XFER doesn't work against enemies.

With the black magic spells SLOW and FAST, which half and double the number of hits of a target respectively, they can basically cancel each other if they both hit a target.